# Smali .local format

Tags: android, dex, smali

I disassembled an Android application with `baksmali`, and studied the produced smali code. One of the classes contains the following line:

```
.local v1, "future":Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/RequestFuture;, "Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/RequestFuture<Ljava/lang/Void;>;"
```

I'm not sure about the meaning of this line of code.

Does `v1` contain a `RequestFuture<Void>`, that corresponds to variable `future` in original code? (i.e. is the original code: `RequestFuture<Void> future;`?) Or is it something different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is part of the debugging information that can optionally be present. It is used when debugging to be able to, e.g. evaluate the value of a local variable.

The .local you mention means exactly what you said. The v1 register holds the value of the `future` variable from the original source, and its type is `RequestFuture<Void>`

A .local directive is equivalent to a `DBG_START_LOCAL` or `DBG_START_LOCAL_EXTENDED` instruction in the debug info for that method, as defined by the [dex format](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html)